# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: state for class: org.hibernate.event.spi.PreDeleteEvent

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.1, audit-logging

```
package products

import fiscalYears.FiscalYear

class Catagorie {
    String productCatagory;

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    String lastUpdatedBy
    String createdBy

    static constraints = {
        lastUpdatedBy nullable: true;
        createdBy nullable: true;
    }
    static belongsTo = [fiscalYear:FiscalYear];

    static auditable = true
    static stampable = true
    def onSave = {
        println "new catagorie  inserted"
        // may optionally refer to newState map
    }
    def onDelete = {
        println "catagorie  was deleted"
        // may optionally refer to oldState map
    }
    def onChange = { oldMap,newMap ->
        println "catagorie  was changed ..."
        oldMap.each({ key, oldVal ->
            if(oldVal != newMap[key]) {
                println " * $key changed from $oldVal to " + newMap[key]
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Insert and update work but I can't delete entity with `.delete()`;
but when commenting `static stampable = true` then delete works.
The following error occurs when delete action is processed:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: state for
>   class: org.hibernate.event.spi.PreDeleteEvent

Comment: Try to use beforeDelete or afterDelete instead

Comment: @ricardogobbo doesn not work